# Is there any point using `-webkit-border-radius` and `-moz-border-radius`?

Tags: cross-browser, css

Or does everything use `border-radius` now?

Comment: Slightly off topic, but a good read none the less: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prefix-or-posthack/

Answer (score 2):

Mozilla Firefox (tested with 3.6.6) doesn't support border-radius, neither does Safari (4.0)

Answer (score 1):

It really just depends on the audience. It's new enough for the lines to still be a bit fuzzy. Check your user's browser statistics if it's at all possible - that's a much better guide than asking the general community because the community experience isn't necessarily going to match your users.

Answer (score 0):

Even if all browsers supported border-radius (they don't see @Aircule's response), you may still want to carry the vender-specific code for legacy browser support. Firefox 3.5 will never support `border-radius`, even if Firefox 4.0 does.

Of course, if your analytics indicate such browsers are irrelevant to your site, such code is unnecessary.

For reference, [PPK keeps current a table of browser CSS3 browser support](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)

Also, if you want to keep your stylesheets light and easy to maintain, you can just use the `border-radius` property, and use [Arron Gustafson's eCSStender JavaScript library](http://ecsstender.org/) to dynamically add `-webkit-` and `-moz-` extensions.